# Emulator Build has been canceled

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wanted to try and create an Android application so I installed VS2017 and included the Xamarin 4.12, designer 4.16 and Xamarin.Android SDK 9.4.4.2. But when I try and build and run the emulator this is the error I am getting

'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe"' -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
Build has been canceled.

I have enable Hyper-V so I am not sure what else I need to do

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

Comment: You do not need Hyper-V to run the emulator. You need to enable Hardware-Acceleration for Virtualisation in your bios. But if you did not do that you would probably get a dicferent error message. Does this problem also occure when you start your emulator using the adb device manager or only when you start your specific application?

Comment: I got the same error message. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable Hardware-Acceleration in the bios on my computer.